# Spring Security BCryptPasswordEncoder Inserted But Not Match

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, security, password-encryption

I have developed a small project on Spring MVC. The project has account table and account has an encoded password with BCryptPasswordEncoder. 
I have used java config instead of XML config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

I get user information and encode the password.

```
@Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    String pass=user.getPassword();
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(pass));
```

In the end, even if I user 123 a password it encoded it but,

```
boolean passstate=pe.matches(pass, user.getPassword());
```

returns false

Comment: Are you sure, that you have correct raw and encoded passwords on every step? Before saving to DB, after retrieving, before matching. Try to log them into a console and check.

Comment: It was so helpful. When I consoled all steps, I figure out the issue that I was encoded twice what a shame

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake, the length of the “password” column (users table) is less than 60, for example, password VARCHAR(45), and some databases will truncate the data automatically. So, you always get the warning “Encoded password does not look like BCrypt”.

To solve it, make sure the length of “password” column is at least 60.

for more details check: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-encoded-password-does-not-look-like-bcrypt/

Comment: This is a not matching problem.