# Spring security authentication failing with BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm new to spring and I'm trying to implement spring security in a project. I was able to create user with hash password using Bcrypt, but whenever I tried to login using the same password it fails. I've also tried checking other SO answers (like [Spring Security BCryptPasswordEncoder Inserted But Not Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471587/spring-security-bcryptpasswordencoder-inserted-but-not-match?rq=1)) non solved the issues faced.

Below is what have tried so far

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/app-assets/**", "/assets/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/add-user", "/users-list").hasRole("ADMIN");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index", "/add-content", "/mange-content").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");

        http
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        //.failureUrl("/login-error.html")
      .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        System.out.println("GOT CALLED HERE.....");
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDAO.findUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User "+username+"not fount");
        }


        List<String> roleNames = roleDAO.getRoleNames(user.getAdminId());

        System.out.println("USERNAME: "+user.getAdminId() + " "+user.getPassword());
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        if (roleNames != null) {
            for (String role : roleNames) {
                GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
                grantList.add(authority);
            }
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantList);


        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

**TEST**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String password = "eureka";
        String encrytedPassword = encoder.encode(password);


        User user = userDAO.findUserByEmail("xxx@gmail.com");

        System.out.println(encrytedPassword);
        System.out.println("Matched: " + encoder.matches("eureka", encrytedPassword));//This line returns true
        assertEquals(encrytedPassword, user.getPassword());
    }
}
```

I also tried overriding matches() but to no avail

```
@Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                // This throws an error
                return matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword);
            }
        };
    }
```

Note: Hashed password and raw password was gotten from matches() method. So there's no issues retrieving hashpassword from database.

Comment: Bcrypt algorithm uses a built-in salt value which is different each time [Spring Security - BcryptPasswordEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324113/spring-security-bcryptpasswordencoder). So your `assertEquals` will not work

Comment: @butiri thanks for your answer... But ain't even talking about the assertEquals I'm talking about trying to login in using a form

Comment: What is the reason it fails? Passwords do not match or there is an exception being thrown somewhere?

Comment: Password do not match... No exception thrown. Thanks

Comment: Did you make any changes to DB after you launched application. If yes, leave DB intact and restart application and share the outcome.

Comment: Thanks all.... I tried deleting the previous data created in the dB and recreated another user. After that I restarted my server boom! It worked. I don't know why or what happened, but it worked!

Comment: which spring-security version you are using?